# canceling file copy operation in windows 7

Tags: windows-7

When I cancel copying files from my PC harddrive to an external drive, why do some files remain on the external drive after canceling? Could this have an effect on the files on my PC that I was trying to copy? (I don't want these files to be corrupted)

Thanks.

Comment: if you copy multiple files they will be copied one by one, so if you cancel the process the already completely transferred files will retain on the destination. You should have corrupted files on the destination if you disconnect the drive during the process.

Comment: Are the files copied one by one if they are contained in folders?

Answer (score 1):

The reason some remain on the external drive is because it is copying them one at a time. As an example, say you have fifty files to copy. You start the copy and on the fourth file decide it will take to long and stop the copy. You should have three files on the destination drive that were done copying before you cancelled it on the fourth file.

To the second question, no, it should not harm any of the source files to cancel the copy before it is finished. You can safely delete any of the files that were already copied to the destination on the destination drive, leaving all source files from your PC in tact.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I am glad canceling the copy does not affect the source files.

Comment: The one-by-one copying process should work the same way whether or not the files are contained in folders. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct, it will still copy things one at a time.